# Manipulating an SVGPath in JavaFX

Tags: java, svg, javafx

Is there a way to examine/manipulate the elements of an [`SVGPath`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/SVGPath.html)? Since it is not derived from `Path` (It is a direct subclass of `Shape`), I can't get the `PathElement`s via `Path`'s `getElements` method.

(In essence, I'd like to use `SVGPath` as an SVG path parser, instead of having to include Apache Batik or writing my own).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an easy way to convert `SVGPath` to `Path` without any third party dependency, based precisely in their common superclass `Shape`'s method `substract`. The result of a substract operation can be downcasted to `Path`:

```
Path path = (Path) (Shape.subtract(svgPath, new Rectangle(0, 0)));
```

So given a certain `SVGPath`, like one of the segments of the SVG [logo](https://www.w3.org/Icons/SVG/svg-logo.svg):

```
SVGPath svgPath = new SVGPath();
svgPath.setContent("M-84.1487,-15.8513 a22.4171,22.4171 0 1 0 0,31.7026 h168.2974 a22.4171,22.4171 0 1 0 0,-31.7026 Z");
svgPath.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
svgPath.setStroke(Color.RED);
```

[image]

you can easily get the `Path` with all the different `PathElement` elements:

```
Path path = (Path)(Shape.subtract(svgPath, new Rectangle(0, 0)));
path.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
path.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
```

and print the elements:

```
path.getElements().forEach(System.out::println);
```

with the following result:

```
MoveTo[x=-99.99996948242188, y=-22.91710090637207]
CubicCurveTo[x=-116.20481872558594, y=-16.20482063293457, controlX1=-105.8649673461914, controlY1=-22.91710090637207, controlX2=-111.72997283935547, controlY2=-20.67967414855957]
...
LineTo[x=83.94287872314453, y=16.351303100585938]
...
ClosePath
```

You can now manipulate the `Path` or any of its elements, but there is no easy way of getting a new `SVGPath` back from the `Path`.

You can find a `ShapeConverter` utility in the JFXtras [project](https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras-labs/blob/8.0/src/main/java/jfxtras/labs/util/ShapeConverter.java). With it you can generate the SVGPath again:

```
SVGPath newSVGPath = ShapeConverter.shapeToSvgPath(path);
```